# Role based authentication using Firebase and ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

*This is a advice seeking type post*

I want to have two user types:

1. User
2. Admin

I'm going to user Firebase for authentication part only. Now let's see what my users can do:

1. Register/login
2. Create post and make it public/private
3. Make a collection of post and make it public/private

And here's what my admin can do:

1. Login
2. CRUD operation on users
3. View public/private posts and delete them
4. View public/private collection of posts and delete them

My question is can I do all of this using just Firebase and ReactJS?
Or do I need a custom backend?

And what my rules for authenticaion for admin and user should look like if I just want a RBAC?

Is this enough?(found it in an article):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && ((auth.token.isAdmin === true && data.child('isAdmin').val() === false) || auth.uid === $user)",
        ".read": "auth !== null && ((auth.token.isAdmin === true && data.child('isAdmin').val() === false) || auth.uid === $user)"
      },
      ".write": "auth !== null && auth.token.isAdmin === true",
      ".read": "auth !== null && auth.token.isAdmin === true"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security rules are enough for what you are trying to do. Your current security rules allow users to read/write their own node only and admins can read/write any user's data.

Custom backend is just an alternative where you use [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and authorize users yourself rather than using security rules. But that sounds an overkill for what you are trying to do unless there's something else you need to do like process the data before adding the database.

Comment: can you provide a sample of what you suggested?
or any article?
I'm new to firebase so I really need some reference

Comment: @FahimHoque the security rules you have are going to work as intended. Are you asking for an example with custom server?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not asking for an example with custom server. I've written some rules but I can't integrate them with my react project. Is there any reference or github repo where I can get some idea about authentication using react+firestore?